# How do I determine if an image has a plain background using HSV values?

Tags: php, image-processing, face-detection

I'm trying to work on something that can detect whether the uploaded photo has a **plain background**. I'm using `imagecolorat()` by using random sample points in a place. The uploaded photos are standard close-up shoulder level photos. I'm checking the color of the pixels in certain locations of the image - somewhere in the background near the ear (of the person) area.

With the results from `imagecolorat()`, I was able to get the RGB color of the points. Then I converted them to HSV.

**How will I be able to determine if the colors are similar?** Since the photos might not necessarily have the exact colors on the sample pixels, I need to put some tolerance level to **allow similar colors**. For instance, `#3A34B9` and `#524EB4` should be okay because they're just both blue with different HSV values but are near each other.

**What should I be checking in the HSV values?** Sometimes gray objects have very distinct HUE and they're still both gray and should pass the test.

I'm not posting any code right now because it's not with the code I'm having problems with, it's with the algorithm on **how I can correctly determine which photos have plain backgrounds or not**.

This isn't really face detection and I wonder if that's possible with PHP but also knowing how I can improve the sample points from the uploaded photo would help. Currently, I only divide the photo in to regions and get the points from specific regions (around 1/6 and 5/6 x-axis, and 1/3 y-axis).

Answer (score 0):

why not compare the RGB values instead of converting them to HSV? You can get the separate 'R', 'G' and 'B' values by bitshifting and masking the result of imagecolorat(). Once you've got these values it is easy to compare them with the rgb values of a test color. I't is also easy to build in some kind of tolerance since every rgb ranges from 0-255. You can easily define how different the R, G and B values can be from your test color.

from the php manual
[imagecolorat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

var_dump($r, $g, $b);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting the use of RGB over HSV?

Comment: The question is, why is he converting a RGB color to HSV? I think RGB is more intuitive when dealing with color comparisons. If you need more red you just have to crank up the R value. The RGB color model works the same as mixing paint in real live. The HSV color model is more complex, that means that the algorithm for comparing these colors will be more complex too. I like to keep it simple which doesn't mean HSV colors can't be useful (for example making gradients)!